# Filter & map an array with Ramda

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ramda.js

I am using Ramda to get the teams with `'Prem League'` in their categories array.
My code looks like the following and it works.

```
import { pipe, map, filter } from 'ramda'   

const teams = [
  {name: 'Liverpool', id: '1', categories: ['Prem League']},
  {name: 'Man Utd', id: '2', categories: ['Blue Square']},
  {name: 'Sheff Utd', id: '2', categories: ['Prem League']},
]

const getTeamOptions = pipe(
    filter((team) => team.categories.includes('Prem League')),
    map((team) => ({ label: team.name, value: team.id }))
);

getTeamOptions(teams)
```

However I want to remove `team` as the argument for filter and `map`.

I tried the following but got `prop(...).includes is not a function`

```
filter(prop('categories').includes('Prem League')),
```

Ideally I would try and remove `team` from `map` too but maybe this is not necessary.

The reason for these changes is that I have been following [this course](https://www.educative.io/courses/functional-programming-patterns-with-ramdajs) and it advises `prop` etc as best practices.

Answer (score 2):

this would also help you solve it with ramda in a point free fashion...

```js
const hasPremLeague = R.where({ categories: R.includes('Prem League') });
const toOption = R.applySpec({ label: R.prop('name'), value: R.prop('id') });

const getTeamOptions = R.into([], R.compose(
  R.filter(hasPremLeague), 
  R.map(toOption),
));

// ---

const teams = [
  {name: 'Liverpool', id: '1', categories: ['Prem League']},
  {name: 'Man Utd', id: '2', categories: ['Blue Square']},
  {name: 'Sheff Utd', id: '2', categories: ['Prem League']},
];

console.log(
  getTeamOptions(teams),
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.0/ramda.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use R.includes to check for the existence of the value. You can generate the new object using R.applySpec:

```js
const { pipe, filter, prop, includes, map, applySpec } = R;

const getTeamOptions = val => pipe(
  filter(pipe(prop('categories'), includes(val))),
  map(applySpec({ label: prop('name'), value: prop('id') }))
);

const teams = [{"name":"Liverpool","id":"1","categories":["Prem League"]},{"name":"Man Utd","id":"2","categories":["Blue Square"]},{"name":"Sheff Utd","id":"2","categories":["Prem League"]}];

const result = getTeamOptions('Prem League')(teams);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.0/ramda.js"></script>
```

Comment: two-loop is expensive, maybe transducer is a good idea

Comment: @PramendraGupta: Do you know that?  Have you tested it?  "Premature optimization is the root of all evil".  Remember that transducers have their own performance issues in JS.

Comment: @ScottSauyet I thought the purpose of  `transduce`?  is `Efficient Data Processing`!

Comment: This is the classic filter and map combo. It's readable, and will have decent performance, unless you have huge arrays. If you have huge arrays, and you need every ounce of performance, I would use a simple for loop, and push to an array to reduce the overhead anyway. Having a hammer doesn't mean that everything is a nail.

Comment: @PramendraGupta: They are designed to improve performance.  But they tend to only manage to do so in JS when the datasets are enormous because of their own overhead.  I'm one of the founders of Ramda, and although I'm impressed with them, I would prefer now that we never included them.  I don't think they're worth the additional weight in the library.  I would suggest that for this problem a `filterMap` implementation would be simpler and more efficient than transducers.

Comment: ... and if it's helpful, a `filterMap` is pretty simple: `const filterMap = (f, m) => (xs) => xs .flatMap ((x) => f (x) ? [m (x)] : [])` (untested.)

Comment: @ScottSauyet i see you post the filterMap function in multiple SO answers and yet it is not part of Ramda. :(

Comment: @Timar: Feel free to make a pull request for one.  It might be worth including.  But there are many things I use regularly that I don't try to include in Ramda.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider a non-Ramda option too.

This may or may not be an abuse of [`Array#flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) but I find it acceptable: filter + map = flatMap

Let's say you want to add 10 to even numbers *and* exclude odd numbers:

```js
[1, 2, 3, 4].flatMap(n => n % 2 === 0 ? n + 10 : []);
//=> [12, 14]
```

There is also a point to be made about pointfree style. It's nice, but sometimes it gets in the way. For example it doesn't allow you to leverage some nice ES6 constructs. For example destructuring:

```js
const getTeamOptions =
  teams =>
    teams.flatMap
      ( ({name: label, id: value, categories}) =>
          categories.includes('Prem League')
            ? { label, value }
            : []
      );

getTeamOptions
  ( [ {name: 'Liverpool', id: '1', categories: ['Prem League']}
    , {name: 'Man Utd', id: '2', categories: ['Blue Square']}
    , {name: 'Sheff Utd', id: '2', categories: ['Prem League']}
    ]
  );

//=> [ {label: "Liverpool", value: "1"}
//=> , {label: "Sheff Utd", value: "2"} ]
```

For completeness, here's a variant using `Array#reduce`:

```js
const getTeamOptions =
  teams =>
    teams.reduce
      ( (acc, {name: label, id: value, categories}) =>
          categories.includes('Prem League')
            ? (acc.push({ label, value }), acc)
            : acc
      , []
      );
```

---

*Don't get me wrong! Ramda is absolutely **amazing**. When I first met this library I wanted to rewrite all my code with it, then I discovered pointfree style and rewrote everything again. In the end I completely lost mental control of my code and that's a problem. You should only use Ramda when it serves you well. In this case you could do without to be honest.*

Answer (score 0):

```
const premLeague = R.equals('Prem League');
const premLeagueInArray = R.any(premLeague);
const categories = R.path(['categories']);
const isPremLeagueInArray = R.pipe(
  categories,
  premLeagueInArray,
);

const teams = [
  { name: "Liverpool", id: "1", categories: ["Prem League"] },
  { name: "Man Utd", id: "2", categories: ["Blue Square"] },
  { name: "Sheff Utd", id: "2", categories: ["Prem League"] },
];
const premLeagueTeam = [
  { name: "Liverpool", id: "1", categories: ["Prem League"] },
  { name: "Sheff Utd", id: "2", categories: ["Prem League"] },
];

const transducer = R.compose(R.filter(isPremLeagueInArray));
const getPremLeagueTeam = R.transduce(transducer, R.flip(R.append), []);

R.equals(getPremLeagueTeam(teams), premLeagueTeam);
```

Comment: Is there a strong reason to believe that `"Prem League"` will be the *first* entry in the array?  Also, this only solves half the problem.

Comment: @ScottSauyet refactored to support any position.

Answer (score 0):

I love to do this in composable way, but currently you are using `pipe` so I do this with `pipe` for consitency. Below is a worked solution

```js
const teams = [
  { name: 'Liverpool', id: '1', categories: ['Prem League'] },
  { name: 'Man Utd', id: '2', categories: ['Blue Square'] },
  { name: 'Sheff Utd', id: '2', categories: ['Prem League'] }
]

const getTeamOptions = pipe(
  filter(
    pipe(
      prop('categories'),
      includes('Prem League')
    )
  ),
  map(
    pipe(
      props(['name', 'id']),
      zipObj(['label', 'value'])
    )
  )
)

console.log(getTeamOptions(teams))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.0/ramda.js"></script>
<script>const { pipe, map, filter, prop, includes, zipObj, props } = R</script>
```